# what data structure for python data reconcile script?

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

I need to reconcile data between two large files and print results in a table.
I already finished reconciling the data by IDs I am not wondering how I can store the rest of the data necessary before I print it the table.
I was first thinking of a dictionary of IDs as keys and dates as values, but I have three dates that I need to find per ID. 
Would the best way be to keep this as a string and then split the string for to get the three dates?
Any advice would help, thanks!

```
ID | ExpDate | StartDate | EndDate
22 | 20141011 | 20120101 | 20140923
66 | 20190920 | 20140101 | 20160923
46 | 20220901 | 20100101 | 20100923
89 | 20250810 | 20110101 | 20220923
```

Comment: What is that? Your expected output? input? *What exactly* do you want to do?

Comment: That's the expected output. 
I have two files with many many more columns. I need to search for the ID I'm interested in and retrieve ExpDate, StartDate, EndDate and store it somehow during my loop before I later print it as shown above. I assume I need to setup a class to hold those values and then create that class object and add dates to the objects fields as I loop.

Comment: Class? I think that's overkill. Why not just put it in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is using a dictionary ( hash ) , as if you saved as a string and you need to change the format ( how are you showing the data ), also a dictionary is a more elegant solution, maintainable and readable,

```
# dict[22] = [20141011, 20120101, 20140923]

dict[id] = [ expDate, startDate, endDate ]


# Format 
print str(id) + ' | ' + ' | '.join(str(x) for x in dict[id])

# Result
# 22 | 20141011 | 20120101 | 20140923
```

Comment: yes, that's perfect. seems to be the easiest and cleanest solution. Thanks!